# When do you need a parameterless constructor on a Command/DTO object for an API call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am getting the following exception thrown: "System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference 
types without parameterless constructor is not supported."

It is JSON being passed into the controller.

When do you need a parameterless constructor vs. one with parameters?

I am using ASP.NetCore.App.Ref 3.1.3 and NetCore.App.Ref 3.1.0.

Here is the class that it is saying needs a parameterless constructor:

```
public class JobApplicationStatusModel : BaseEntityModel
{
    /// <summary>
    ///JobApplicationStatus ID
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description/Name of Status.
    /// </summary>
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">JobApplication StatusID</param>
    /// <param name="statusDescription">Status Description</param>
    public JobApplicationStatusModel(int id, string statusDescription)
    {
        Id = id;
        StatusDescription = statusDescription ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(statusDescription));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumeration of all atomic values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An enumeration of all  atomic values.</returns>
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        // Using a yield return statement to return each element one at a time
        yield return Id;
        yield return StatusDescription;
    }
    }
```

Comment: How does a deserializer know which parameters value pass to your constructor (id & statusDescription) ? It can't. So it requires a parameterless constructor to deserialize your data

Comment: Agree with Steve.